# Collection Views: Can cellForItemAtIndexPath be triggered, manually?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

In my **UICollectionViewController.m**, I build a string array of image filenames inside the **(void)viewDidLoad** method which I'd like to later use in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method to populate a grid. The issue however is that the **cellForItemAtIndexPath** seems to execute before the array from **viewDidLoad** has a chance to get created.

I'm new to **Collection Views** and would like to better understand how this is normally used/controlled. I was wondering if after I build my array I could call **cellForItemAtIndexPath**.

Comment: works like all other controls that have a dataSource, a coreplot, a tableview, an image browser... all offer reloadData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call reloadData instance method of collectionView after creating you array.

//build array

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: I just have a new problem to resolve now which is, every time I move the vertical scroll up or down it seems to hit the cellForItemAtIndexPath method again and again. I've placed my NSURL, NSData, UIImage code into this method which I'm not sure if its the correct thing to do.

Comment: You are reusing cells, hence cellForItemAtIndexPath will get called each time new cell becomes visible. Table view loads cells which are visible. Getting image from server in cellForItemAtIndexPath will only affect your table view's performance.